# Как менять данные сайта, не пересаливая код?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть благотворительный сайт, где нужно постоянно обновлять информацию о собранных средствах. На данный момент я хардкодю каждый раз число в код. Сложноть этог метода связана с тем что сервер находить не у меня и проходит время пока я передам код и он зальет его.

Если ли возможноть создать на сайте что-нибудь что позволить мне менять число не перезаливая код на сервер? Может быть тестовое поле. Желательно чтобы оно было видно только мне, либо доступ к нему был бы ограничен паролем.

Comment: Вопрос номер раз - откуда сервер сможет узнать, какое число показать? Где оно еще записано, кроме Вашей головы?

Comment: Нужно разлюбить

Comment: найдите человека который понимает как нужно делать сайты и попросите его вам сделать страницу

Comment: на каком языке планируете реализовать работу сайта для динамического обновления?

Comment: Покажите код вашего сервера, где  и как у вас пишется сумма.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант, это отображать сумму пожертвований в iframe, в котором будет храниться только сумма. Тогда придется менять текст в файлике, в котором хранится только сумма, а не html код сайта.

Если хотите сделать что-то более правильное, то придется использовать php/asp/etc, что повлечет изучения какой-то части языка программирования.

Comment: А можно поизвращаться и сделать репозиторий на `git`, в котором будет единственный файл с суммой. А с клиента через `script` этот файл подключать и он будет выводить сумму.